# Mysqldump creates empty file when run via cron on linux

Tags: bash, mysql

I have a bash script mysql_cron.sh that runs mysqldump

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -ujoe -ppassword > /tmp/somefile
```

This works fine.  I then call it from cron:

```
20 * * * * /home/joe/mysql_cron.sh
```

and this creates the file /tmp/somefile, but the file is always empty.  I have tried adding a

```
source /home/joe/.bash_profile
```

to the script to make sure cron has the right env variables, but that doesn't help. I see many other people having this problem but have found no solution.  I've also tried the '>' operator in the crontab to cat any cron errors to a file, but that doesn't seem to generate any errors.  Any troubleshooting ideas welcomed.  Thanks!

Comment: If mysqldump's failing for whatever reason, it should issue that reason to stderr, which cron would be emailing to the account under which the job's running. Check that account's mail box and see what cron's reporting.

Comment: Or you can add `2> /tmp/mycronerrorfile` at the end of you bash command : `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -ujoe -ppassword > /tmp/somefile 2> /tmp/mycronerrorfile` to get the possible error in a file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add output of error information to file (as Damp has said), so that you can check if there is any error:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -ujoe -ppassword > /tmp/somefile 2>&1
```

You can also take a look at MySQL's log files at `/var/log` in case there is some hint there.

Comment: Thanks!  I had forgotten the '2' in redirecting error output, so now I have the error, which lead me to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your script and compare the result between running it from cron versus running it directly:

```
env > /tmp/env.$$.out
```

The `$$` will be replaced in the resulting filename by the PID of the parent process (cron or the shell). You should be able to `diff` the two files and see if anything significant is different between the two environments.